# Archive giant folder in Linux using command line without termination

Tags: linux, terminal, timeout, tar, gzip

Well, I'm just trying to compress a whole directory (infact giant!) under Linux using a terminal. The entire folder size is about 7 GB. I've used below command to create the archive.

```
tar -zcvf myArchieve.tar.gz myFolder
```

It's working but in middle it stops by displaying `Terminated` message in the terminal. I could see the archive file created but there were missing file(s)/sub folder(s). in the compressed file. I want to create the entire folder (7 GB) Archive without any 'Terminated' message timeout. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have to find out what the process was terminated. There is no such thing as a timeout for this command. So there must be a different reason. Maybe someone else sent a `sighub` because the command slowed the system down? Maybe you accidentially terminated the command still running in background?

Comment: @arkascha No, after executing it for 5 Minutes, displayed a message 'Terminated' that's it.

Comment: "terminated" in unixoid cli utilities usually means that the process received a signal to terminal (`sigterm`) from outside. That might be from some user or from the system. But the command certainly did _not_ terminate itself!

Comment: Do you have OOM messages in your syslog?